# Deleting Notifications by Using Signals in a Django Project depending on Value of Attribute

Tags: python, django

I have added a notification everytime a user has submits Like button to a post, the owner of the liked post receives a notification, but I am now receiving a notification everytime the button is click either by unliking or liking, so I have added value for the Like so that it can be `Like` and `Unlike`.

So, now in the Notifications I have added the delete option but I am a bit confused on how to set delete the Noification if the value of the like is `Unlike`, to prevent receiving unwanted notifications.

Here is the post models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='liked', blank=True)
```

Here is the likes models.py

```
LIKE_CHOICES = (
    ('Like', 'Like'),
    ('Unlike', 'Unlike')
)


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(choices=LIKE_CHOICES, default='Like', max_length=8)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post}-{self.user}-{self.value}"

    def user_liked_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        post = like.post
        sender = like.user
        notify = Notification(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.save()

    def user_unlike_post(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        like = instance
        post = like.post
        sender = like.user
        notify = Notification.objects.filter(post=post, sender=sender, user=post.author, notification_type=1)
        notify.delete()

# Likes
post_save.connect(Like.user_liked_post, sender=Like)
post_delete.connect(Like.user_unlike_post, sender=Like)
```

Here is the notifications models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    NOTIFICATION_TYPES=((1,'Like'),(2,'Comment'),(3,'Follow'))

    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_post", blank=True, null=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_from_user")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="noti_to_user")
    notification_type= models.IntegerField(choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPES)
    text_preview= models.CharField(max_length=90,blank=True)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_seen=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the views.py, I have commented my trial as it didn't work

```
def ShowNotifications(request):
    user=request.user
    notifications= Notification.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date')
    template= loader.get_template('notifications/notifications.html')
    # if Like.value == 'Like':
    #     return Like.user_liked_post
    # if Like.value == 'Unlike':
    #     return Like.user_unlike_post

    context= {
        'notifications':notifications
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

The current situation:

1. Currently when a user likes a post notification is sent
2. When the same user unlikes also a Like notification is sent

Required output:

1. when a user likes a post notification is sent
2. When the same user unlikes the previously sent notification is deleted